# Is it possible to obtain negative electric field E?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Electric Field formula is E = − Δ V Δ s.

The electric field is said to be the gradient (as in grade or slope) of the electric potential. In that case, for the electric potential well around a negative charge (from the perspective of a positive charge), the gradient will always be positive as in the case of gravitational potential wells. In this case, because of the negative sign, wouldn't the electric field, which is defined as the negative of the rate of change of electric potential, be always negative?

It is known that electric field E is always positive, but I think this contradicts that theory.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html

Comment: I do not recognize this expression.

Answer (score 2):

Electric fields can be negative.

The electric field is, by definition, the force per unit of charge exerted on a small positive charge at that point. Let's say for illustration that we have two point charges, $+$ and $-$, on the x-axis. Then a positive point charge in between the two would move towards the right, i.e. the direction of the electric field is positive. But if we replaced the two charges with $-$ and $+$, a positive point charge would move towards the left, i.e. the direction of the electric field is negative.

This shouldn't be too surprising since the electric field is a vector field, and vectors can be positive and negative.

Comment: *vectors can be positive and negative* Two vectors can be the negatives of each other, but there is no such thing as a “negative vector”, or a positive one. The magnitude is *non*-negative, and the direction is not a single quantity that could even have a sign.

Comment: @G.Smith I was going to write something like that, but I can't even begin to imagine what a vector with a negative magnitude would be like. From there, I would interpret a sentence such as "the electric field is negative" as completely directional.

Comment: The OP’s belief that the electric field is “positive” or “negative” is simply a misconception. I feel that your answer reinforced this misconception.

Comment: The OP is apparently thinking only in one-dimensional terms. This is a bad way to think because the world is not one-dimensional. In my way of thinking, even a one-dimensional vector cannot be negative, although its sole component can be.

Comment: @G.Smith depending on what the OP says (if anything), I'll edit the answer.